# Disable Unit Test MSTest

Tags: c++, mstest

I have been tasked with repairing our decrepid unit test framework and I'm simply trying to disable a few failing tests, but I don't know how to do this in code.  In C#, it's as simple as adding the [Ignore] attribute and, in C++, I figured out how to disable all of them for a particular class, but I want to do it with specific tests as well:

```
BEGIN_TEST_CLASS_ATTRIBUTE()
TEST_CLASS_ATTRIBUTE(L"Ignore", L"true")
END_TEST_CLASS_ATTRIBUTE()
```

Does anyone know how to disable a specific unit test in a source file in C++ using the MSTest framework?  Thanks in advance, Google has not been of much help!

Comment: > I figured out how to disable all of them for a particular class

How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
BEGIN_TEST_METHOD_ATTRIBUTE(Test_Name)
TEST_METHOD_ATTRIBUTE(L"Ignore", L"true")
END_TEST_METHOD_ATTRIBUTE()
TEST_METHOD(Test_Name)
{
    // code
}
```

Or this:

```
BEGIN_TEST_METHOD_ATTRIBUTE(Test_Name)
    TEST_IGNORE()
END_TEST_METHOD_ATTRIBUTE()
TEST_METHOD(Test_Name)
{
    // code
}
```

Check More [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh694604.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#BKMK_Test_method_attributes)